# PHP обрезать текст от слова до слова

Tags: php

Есть текст вида:

Вопрос: Как купить автомобиль безопасно?
Ответ: Прежде всего, нужно обратиться в компанию...

Мне нужно убрать из текст всё начиная со слова "Вопрос" и до слова "Ответ", то есть фразу "Вопрос: Как купить автомобиль безопасно?".

Как это сделать через PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать регулярное выражение. Будет обрезан весь текст до последнего паттерна `Ответ:`. Таким образом этот код сломается только в том случае, если в ответе паттерн встретится более чем 1 раз.

```
$str = 'Вопрос: Как купить автомобиль безопасно ответ? Ответ: не ясен. Ответ: Прежде всего, нужно обратиться в компанию...';
$res = preg_replace('/.*(?=Ответ:)/u', '', $str);
var_dump($res);
```

[Run](https://3v4l.org/TtZcc#v8.0.10)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/**
 * Массив $data
 * @params $data['text'] - наш текст, с которым мы будем работать
 * @params $data['beginning'] - слово до которого мы будем обрезать наш текст.
 */
$data = [
    'text' => 'Вопрос: Как купить автомобиль безопасно? Ответ: Прежде всего, нужно обратиться в компанию...',
    'beginning' => 'Ответ'
];



$string = strpos($data['text'], $data['beginning']);
$result = substr($data['text'], 0, $string);

echo $result;
```

Мне совершенно непонятно, зачем вам это? Ведь куда лучше "вопрос" и "ответ" хранить в разных местах, так как пользователь в самом вопросе может написать слово "ответ" и тогда текст обрежеться на середине его предложения.

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Да, сейчас так и планируем делать - хранить в раздельных полях. Переносим базу данных старого сайта, и там весь текст в одном поле, который нам нужно разделить для новой структуры бд.